# data-add-back-btn="true" not working when adding changeHash: false property to changePage

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an issue with data-add-back-btn="true". it was working fine but when i added the changeHash: false to changePage, the data-add-back-btn="true" doesn't return me to the previous page. it is taking me to the root always. the code is as below:

$.mobile.changePage("#CountriesPage", { changeHash: false });

< div data-role="page" id="CountriesPage" data-add-back-btn="true" >

Any help!!

Answer (score 1):

The back button relies on the changeHash to work as expected. Your going to have to get rid of one or the other.